# How can I call a class with variables from array php?

Tags: php, arrays, class

I would like something like this but dynamically from an array like this:

```
$array = array("first","second","third");
```

So class would be called like this:

```
$class = new class("first","second","third");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection for it:

```
$refClass = new ReflectionClass('SomeClass');
$instance = $refClass->newInstanceArgs($args);
```

Comment: meant for the first not reflection  (call_user_func)